# How to fix the error with std:ifstreambuf_iterator<char32_t>?

Tags: c++, utf-8, character-encoding, utf-32

I have this simple code, which have to iterate four bytes from file and pass it to function utf8::utf32to8, which will convert file from utf32 encoding to utf8:

```
ifstream my_file(sourceFilePath, std::ifstream::binary);

vector<unsigned char> res_utf8;
utf8::utf32to8(std::istreambuf_iterator<char32_t>(my_file),
               std::istreambuf_iterator<char32_t>(),
               back_inserter(res_utf8));
out.write((char*)&res_utf8[0], res_utf8.size());
```

But when I compile I get this error:

```
error: invalid user-defined conversion from 'std::ifstream {aka std::basic_ifstream<char>}' to 'std::istreambuf_iterator<char32_t>::streambuf_type* {aka std::basic_streambuf<char32_t, std::char_traits<char32_t> >*}' [-fpermissive]
         utf8::utf32to8(std::istreambuf_iterator<char32_t>(my_file),
                                                                  ^
```

Please, help me complie this code successfully.

Comment: The types don't match up. Maybe declaring `my_file` as `basic_ifstream<char32_t> my_file` will help.

Comment: no, it doesn't help.

Comment: Are you still getting the same error?

Comment: hey, no, I don't get error during compilation, but I get an exception: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_cast'
  what():  std::bad_cast